# How to get the data using where_in (1,3 ) table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, where

We have 2 Tables

Table 1 is User

Table 1:

```
 id  |  name     |   sub_code    
-----------------------------
  1  |    name1  |    1  
  2  |    name2  |    1,3  
  3  |    name3  |    2,4
```

Table 2 is Sub

Table 2:

```
  sub_id  |  sub_name  
-----------------------
  1       |      sub1    
  2       |      sub2      
  3       |      sub3 
  4       |      sub4
```

We need the following result:

```
 name2 | sub1, sub3
```

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in a single column. That is a really bad idea. The best solution is to fix your data model.

Comment: Use FIND_IN_SET() for joining tables, then GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT(). And I 100% agree with @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it okay, But it is old database now we can't change the data model